# Placing cursor in the document for a given position using PyUNO

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, pyuno

I am having Libreoffice7 installed with custom python 3.8.6 in Windows.
**I want to use PyUNO to navigate the view cursor to a specific position based on the X, Y coordinates(of instance com.sun.star.awt.Point) in a writer document**.
Is there a way by which this can be achieved? I am unable to find any resource or documentation that helps.
Please let me know if any other info or clarifications needed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Precise positioning using [points and pixels](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/XUnitConversion.html) is difficult or impossible with the UNO API. The numbers  seem to be unpredictable, for example https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/what-is-the-base-for-cursor-x-position-in-basic/71827.

Instead, move the cursor to a character or paragraph or object, for example with [goRight()](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextCursor.html).

To investigate point positioning further, take a look at this discussion on positioning a dialog in Calc: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/dynamically-position-a-dialog/67289/39